# Implicit interface implementation

Tags: java, interface

I have the following `MyOpt` interface:

```java
public interface MyOpt<T> {
    T get();
    boolean isPresent();
}
```

And the class method, that returns one of `MyOpt` implementations:

```java
private MyOpt<String> read() { ... }
```

At the same time, `Optional` has the same methods and signatures and can be `MyOpt` subtype. But when refactor class method to return `Optional` like this:

```java
private <X extends MyOpt<String>> X read() {
    Optional<String> empty = Optional.empty();
    return empty;
}
```

IntelliJ shows this error:

```
Required type: X

Provided: Optional<java.lang.String>
```

How can I use `Optional` as an implementation of `MyOpt`?

Comment: You say "`Optional` can be a subtype of `MyOpt`", but it is not defined that way. Just because `Optional` has the same methods as `MyOpt`, does not mean you can treat `Optional` as if it is a subtype of `MyOpt`. To answer your question: "How can I use `Optional` as an implementation of `MyOpt`?", the answer is: you cannot. Java simply does not support [structural typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).

Comment: The java solution to this is to use a optional wrapper that implements `MyOpt`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use Optional as an implementation of MyOpt?

You cannot.

`Optional` is a `final class` defined in the JDK.  Just because you share the same method names and types, does not mean you can treat your class as related to `Optional` in any way.